# Get input from textarea to sort and print out. I am getting in data but am not able to sort nor print out.

Tags: javascript

```
<html>
<body>
```

//My text area

```
<textarea id="emailTextarea" rows ="30" cols="30" >
sara@yahoo.com
adam@yahoo.com
todd@yahoo.com
henry@yahoo.com
wright@yahoo.com
</textarea>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>
```

//Getting input from the textarea for the email list

```
    //The email list
    var emailList = document.getElementById("emailTextarea").value;
```

//function to remove the yahoo extension

```
    //remove the extension
    var emailUserHash = emailList.reduce(function(emailUsers, email, i) {
        var username = email.slice(0, email.indexOf('yahoo.com'));
        if(!emailUsers[username]) emailUsers[username] = true;
        return emailUsers;
    }, {});
```

//calling the emailUserHash function

```
    //call the emailUserHash function
    var emailUsers = Object.keys(emailUserHash)
```

//Sort the email list

```
    //sort the email list
    emailUsers.sort();
```

//Print out the list

```
    //output the list
    document.write(emailUsers.join('</br>'));
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: Try to debug it with `alert()`; print out `emailUsers`, etc.

Comment: Where is the actual question? It should be in the body of your post. Anyhow, *emailList* is a string, *reduce* is a method of arrays. Perhaps you mean to split the string on new lines to get an array, then you can use *reduce*. *Object.keys* on an array isn't going to help (here). Seems to me *replace* will do the job more efficiently.

Comment: `emailList.reduce` is not a function?

Answer (score 0):

Think this might be what you are trying to accomplish:

```
var emailList = document.getElementById("emailTextarea").value;
var emailListArray = emailList.split("\n");

var usernamesArray = emailListArray.map(function(val, index, arr) {
    return val.slice(0, val.indexOf('@yahoo.com'));
});

var sortedUsernames = usernamesArray.sort();

document.write(sortedUsernames.join('</br>'));
```

This will output the list of email usernames sorted and with the @yahoo.com removed

Comment: Could you tell me how you could remove the duplicates from usernamesArray?

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9229645/remove-duplicates-from-javascript-array

Answer (score 0):

You shall parse your textarea to array.

I made example with JQuery: https://jsfiddle.net/k8te23mf/

```
var arrayOfLines = $('#emailTextarea').val().split('@yahoo.com\n');
$('#demo').append(arrayOfLines+', ');
```